# Raw sql query returns multiple rows, but with Joomla methods only one row is returned

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, virtuemart, jdatabase

For some reason the query I put directly to DB works, but when set in Joomla syntax it is returning only 1 result, and there should be a lot more...

**Clear Mysql query:**

```
SELECT 
vmp.virtuemart_product_id as 'product_id',
vmp.product_parent_id as 'parent_id',
vmp.product_sku as 'sku',
vmp.product_in_stock as 'stock',
vmp.published as 'published',
pc.virtuemart_category_id as "category"
FROM `mus_virtuemart_products` as vmp
JOIN mus_virtuemart_product_categories as pc ON pc.virtuemart_product_id=vmp.product_parent_id
WHERE vmp.product_parent_id>0 AND pc.virtuemart_category_id=105;
```

**Joomly query:**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array(
                    'vmp.virtuemart_product_id as product_id',
                    'vmp.product_parent_id as parent_id',
                    'vmp.product_sku as sku',
                    'vmp.product_in_stock as stock',
                    'vmp.published as published',
                    'pc.virtuemart_category_id as category'
                    ))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products','vmp'))
      ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_product_categories','pc') . 
        ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_product_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('vmp.virtuemart_product_id') . ')')        
      ->where($db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_category_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($category). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('vmp.product_parent_id') . ' >0');
$db->setQuery($query);
$podaci = $db->loadAssocList();
```

I have tried various combinations, and am always getting only 1 result.
I think I have limited the issue to 1 condition in the WHERE clause:

```
->where($db->quoteName('vmp.product_parent_id') . ' >0');
```

I have tried to set "zero" as `$db->quote($zero)` where `$zero="0"`, but didn't change anything.

---

## UPDATE 1

After a few iterations in my code I start getting an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

When I change my `where` condition to only `$db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_category_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($category)` the query works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error in my query.

Original:

```
JOIN mus_virtuemart_product_categories as pc ON pc.virtuemart_product_id=vmp.product_parent_id
```

Joomla query:

```
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_product_categories','pc') . 
    ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_product_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('vmp.virtuemart_product_id') . ')')
```

- The last column reference should be replaced.

Instead of `vmp.virtuemart_product_id` it should be `vmp.product_parent_id`

So the final correct query is:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array(
                    'vmp.virtuemart_product_id as product_id',
                    'vmp.product_parent_id as parent_id',
                    'vmp.product_sku as sku',
                    'vmp.product_in_stock as stock',
                    'vmp.published as published',
                    'pc.virtuemart_category_id as category'
                    ))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products','vmp'))
      ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_product_categories','pc') . 
        ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_product_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('vmp.product_parent_id') . ')')        
      ->where($db->quoteName('pc.virtuemart_category_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($category). ' AND '. $db->quoteName('vmp.product_parent_id') . ' >0');
$db->setQuery($query);
$podaci = $db->loadAssocList();
```

Comment: I have moved your solution from the question to your answer.  Please take the [tour] to begin to learning how to post/interact on this site.  After an amount of time, you will be able to award your own answer the big green tick (please do this--it is important). For your information: 1. there is an `innerJoin()` method 2. The `where()` method accepts an array of conditions with a default glue of `AND` (this will likely improve the readability of your script) 3. Your `ON` condition does not need the extra parentheses to maintain logic.

Comment: Relevant posts: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/24867/12352 and https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/23041/12352